# Receive error when printing field

Tags: theming, entities, nodes

Hi i've just started building a site on Drupal 7.31 and i'm following my normal procedure i've used loads of times. One of the things I have on most sites is an introduction just beneath the title.

I add an introduction field to the Basic Page content type and in page.tpl.php I print it out using:

```
<?php
    if (isset($node)) {
      if ($node->type == 'page') {

        print '<h2>';
        print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_introduction', array('label'=>'hidden'))); 
        print '</h2>';

      } 
    }
?>
```

It's never caused any problems before, on any previous version but for some reason this time round I get this error:

```
Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in include()
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/render/7) function receives an arguemnt as reference, you should pass a variable instaed of function:

```
$var = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_introduction', array('label'=>'hidden'));
print render($var);
```